# Does SAS have a way to collapse code like #region in .net?

Tags: sas

I have some commented code in a SAS program that i would like to be able to collapse. How can i do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make your code easier to read, in addition to itzy's comment, you can use %include to include code from other files; just like c# or other c-based languages, then, you can write individual modules for even very small sections of code and bring them in via %include.  You can even bring them in as macros to call them repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows, any code written in the Enhanced Program Editor will do this automatically. That is, any `data` or `proc` statements will open a collapse region.

Comment: But I don't think you can collapse the comment block by itself. Comment is always attached to the next data or proc block and it collapses with that block.